# Can someone provide a description where the Jacobian would be used in probability for variable transformation?

Tags: probability

It seems to me like all the transformations that I have done in the text book  can be dealt with the Distribution function of the transform method. I was wondering if someone would be able to create an example that would showcase the use of the Jacobian matrix and hopefully help me understand intuitively what is going on?

Comment: You mean, the Jacobian *determinant*? Then the radial representation of 2-dim standard normal random variables seems a must.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with Gamma distributions
$$
\frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} \left( \frac x \lambda \right)^\alpha e^{-x/\lambda} \ \frac{dx} x \text{ on }(0,\infty)\quad\text{and}\quad \frac 1 {\Gamma(\beta)} \left( \frac y \lambda \right)^\beta e^{-y/\lambda} \ \frac{dy} y \text{ on }(0,\infty).
$$
Let
$$
\begin{cases} U = X + Y, \\[10pt]  V = \dfrac X {X+Y}. \end{cases} 
$$
Show that

- $U$ has a Gamma distribution $$ \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)} \left( \frac u \lambda \right)^{\alpha+\beta} e^{-u/\lambda}\ \frac{du} u \quad\text{on }(0,\infty), $$ and
- $V$ has a Beta distribution $$ \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} v^{\alpha-1} (1-v)^{\beta-1} \, dv \text{ on } (0,1),  $$ and
- $U,V$ are independent.

Another example is the derivation of the density of the usual $F$-distribution, showing it's (if I recall correctly!) the square root of a rational function.  Remember that it is
$$
\frac{\chi^2_n/n}{\chi^2_m/m}
$$
where the two chi-square random variables are independent.